# Is it possible to display the embed color palette of a TIFF file using earthPy?

Tags: python, color, matplotlib, earthpy

I try to display a map that I have created. This map embed a color palette that I can read in QGIS to obtain directly this kind of display :

[image]

I discovered recently that I can as well directly plot this image using `earthPy.plot`:

```py
raster = pm.getGfcDir() + 'PU_glad_check.tif'

# Use rasterio to import the reprojected data as img
with rio.open(raster) as src:
    img = src.read()
    
ax = ep.plot_bands(
    img,
    title="Country boundaries",
    scale=False
)
```

But it's displayed with a gray-scale from 0 to 255. I've been to this [doc](https://earthpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery_vignettes/plot_draw_legend_docs.html) page that explains how to create a custom discrete legend but I'd like to extract it from my file.

Is there a way to use the embed color palette as in QGIS but in `earthPy`?

Comment: of course and this page explain how to set a random color palette from a numpy created matrix. My color palette exist within the image and I would like to extract it

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. Instead, [Edit] the Question.

Comment: There was another comment when I commented, it has been deleted. I'm adding the required info to the question